# Rectangle IsFocused doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I have a `slider` and I want its thumb to change style depending on its state: mouse over or clicked. 
I did try changing the thumb's style, but for no apparent reason it did nothing by the way. 
So this rectangle, The `IsMouseOver` works just fine, but as I said, the `IsFocused` does nothing.

My XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderRectStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
<Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF5B5B5B"/>
<Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF5B5B5B"/>
<Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
<Setter Property="mouseHelper:MouseDownHelper.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFF0A300"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFF0A300"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFD1A139"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FFD1A139"/>
        </Trigger>

   </Style.Triggers>

 </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `IsFocusable` property of the `Rectangle` to `true` and actually focus it by calling its `Focus()` method to focus it:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Style="{StaticResource SliderRectStyle}" Width="100" Height="100" Focusable="True" 
                   PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="rect_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

---

```
private void rect_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rect.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem left is that this rect is inside a thumb style (that is used by the slider style) and for no apparent reason my XAML.cs doesn't see the name I gave my rect. How to get around this?

Comment: You need to get a reference to the Rectangle in the visual tree then but thatäs Another story. Please ask a new question if you have Another issue and make sure to include all relevant code snippets for anyone to be able to reproduce your issue from scratch: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: True that one and sorry to be confusing. I plan to google the visual tree thing first of course.